# lit-element not rendering nested (child) components for copy/paste/print

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

I am trying to add copy/paste and print functionality to a tree of nested lit-elements.  I am trying to get the nested components to render so I may push the full html+style in a string into the copy/paste buffer and also into an iframe or hidden div for printing.

The code can be found here: https://mjmihk.stackblitz.io

My approach is to select the parent and get the shadow DOM's contents, but this appears to yield a 'shallow rendering'.  I would expect to see the `<p>` tags nested within the bounds of the `<child-greeting>` tags.

```
var elem: any = document.querySelector("simple-greeting");
var cpRoot = elem.shadowRoot.querySelector("#cproot");
```

When trying this, the copy paste content is not 'deeply' rendering the child elements:

```
<p>Hello, World!</p>
<child-greeting name="Peter"></child-greeting>
<child-greeting name="Constance"></child-greeting>
```

Any help here appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to 'dive' into the shadowRoots; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170043/how-can-i-clone-a-shadowroot

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to help with this with the source (rather than the output) link at https://stackblitz.com/edit/mjmihk

First of all:

```
var elem: any = document.querySelector("simple-greeting");
```

Gets the first instance of this component in the `document`, so will fail if you have more than one. You don't need this, as any event subscribed with Lit's `@` syntax will be called with `this` as the current element.

That means your next line should be:

```
const cpRoot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#cproot");
```

However, there's a better way again to get that using LitElement's `@query` decorator:

```
@query('#cproot') private cpRoot: HTMLDivElement;

_handlePrintClick() {
    console.log("copy/paste/print content:", this.cpRoot.innerHTML);
}
```

Your next problem is `innerHTML` - this gets the *light* DOM. With web components you now have two types of document - the HTML you put inside the component, and a new isolated HTML that component owns.

For instance, if you had:

```html
<child-greeting name="Peter">
    #shadow-root [<p>I am the child. ...!</p>]

    <p>Something else about Peter</p>
</child-greeting>
```

(And `child-greeting` had a `<slot>`) then `innerHTML` will give you `<p>Something about Peter</p>`, which is the light DOM. Your shadow DOM (the `<p>I am the child. ...!</p>` bit) isn't included.

For most custom elements this is *exactly* what you want, as the shadow DOM will hold the component part - the dropdown on a select or date picker, the action buttons on a rich text input, etc. Many browsers use then internally - for instance `<video>` has shadow DOM that renders the play button, progress bar, etc.

You have two options:

1. Break shadow DOM on elements you want to expose their content to `innerHTML`. You can do this with LitElement by overriding the method that creates the shadow DOM fragment to return the control instead:

```
createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
}
```

2. Access the DOM directly rather than using `innerHTML`. This would require recursion down the tree checking for `shadowRoot` on every element, and any that used `<slot>` will have to have their DOM tree rebuilt to put nested light DOM content into it.

Neither of these is particularly easy, and both have compromises.